# SQLite database crashing

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having difficulty with using an SQLite database with Android, and whenever my application tries to interact with the database it crashes. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the constructor, onCreate() and onUpgrade() methods:

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //SQL to create the rTable
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + rTable +
    "(" + colID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
    colValue + " Integer, " + colDate + " Date, " + colNotes + "TEXT, ");

    //SQL to create the limit table
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + lTable +
    "(" + colLimitID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
    colLimitUpper + " Integer, " + colLimitLower + " Integer, " +
    colLimitDate + " Date, ");

    //Create view containing all results
    db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW " + viewR +
    " AS SELECT " + rTable + "." + colID + " AS _id," +
    " " + rTable + "." + colValue + "," +
    " " + rTable + "." + colDate + "," +
    " " + rTable + "." + colNotes + "," +
    " FROM " + rTable
    );
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //Used to upgrade the database if the schema needs to be changed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + rTable);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + lTable);
    db.execSQL("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS " + viewR);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

This is an example method which I am using to update a row in the table:

```
public int UpdateRows(Object obj) {
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(colValue, obj.getValue());
    cv.put(colNotes, obj.getNotes());
    return db.update(rTable, cv, colID+"=?",
    new String []{String.valueOf(obj.get_id())});
}
```

Below is a method I'm using to view all of the rows:

```
public List<Object> getAll() {
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();

    List<Object> List= new ArrayList<>();

    String query = "SELECT * from " +tTable;


    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);


    if(c!=null){
        c.moveToFirst();


        while(c.isAfterLast()){
            //Create object
            Object obj = new Object("1", "100", "", "");
            //Set result values equal to that of result in this row
            obj.set_id(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(colID)));
            obj.setDate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(colDate)));
            obj.setValue(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(colValue)));
            obj.setNotes(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(colNotes)));

            //Add object to list
            List.add(obj);

            //Move cursor to next row
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        //Close cursor
        c.close();
    }
    //Return list
    return List;
}
```

Comment: How does it crash? Do you have traceback or something?

Comment: share with us your stacktrace

Comment: I've not managed to catch any exceptions..but then I'm not really sure what I'm doing with that

Comment: If you can't catch exceptions, try at least to debug the code in single step mode, and you will see where it crashes.

Comment: Why did you delete the content of the question after it got resolved? I recommend you put it how it was for people in the future who have the same problem you're having now.

Comment: How has it been resolved? You can insert your own solution as an answer, if you have resolved it yourself, or click the ckeckmark next to the answer which solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your SQL commands is wrong. After removing the string operators and string delimiters they look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE resultTable
(colID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 colValue Integer, colDate Date, colNotesTEXT,

CREATE TABLE limitTable
(colLimitID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 colLimitUpper Integer, colLimitLower Integer, colLimitDate Date,

CREATE VIEW viewResults
AS SELECT resultTable.colID AS _id,
resultTable.colValue,
resultTable.colDate,
resultTable.colNotes,
FROM resultTable
```

The CREATE TABLE commands end with a comma and the right brace is missing. Replace the last comma by a right brace. Note that the right brace in your code is part of programm code and not inside the sql command string. And also a space between `colNotes` and "TEXT" is missing.

The CREATE VIEW has a comma just before the FROM. Remove this comma.

---

Using the [formatter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html) would make the code more readable and less error prone.

```
string cmd = format(
    "CREATE TABLE %s (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, %s Integer, %s Date, %s TEXT)",
    resultTable, colID, colValue, colDate, colNotes);
db.execSQL(cmd);
```